# Get or set AjaxControlToolkit HTMLEditor content via javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an aspx file that uses HTMLEditor and Tabs of AjaxControlToolkit.
The code is below

```
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="panelBanner" HeaderText="Banner">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelBanner" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <cc1:MeritAjaxEditor runat="server" ID="editor_BANNER" Height="350px" ActiveMode="Preview"
                        ReadOnly="true" />

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="panelPOS" HeaderText="POS">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelPOS" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <cc1:MeritAjaxEditor runat="server" ID="editor_POS" Height="350px" ActiveMode="Preview"
                        ReadOnly="true" />

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

What i need is to set the content of each editor through javascript function. 
I already tried the $get and $find methods but i cant find the editor.

var editorControl = $get("<%=editor.ClientID%>").control;
//1. For setting content:
editorContorl.set_content("Sample Content");

Please let me know if you know how to get the editors

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML Editors then try using this:

```
var controlid = '<%=editor.ClientID%>';
var control = $find(controlid)._editPanel._modePanels[0];
control.insertHTML('test html message');
```

Reference link [ASP.NET Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1434893.aspx/1?htmleditor+client+side+functionality)

Thanks & Regards,

Harsh Baid